# Windows equivalent to UNIX pwd

Tags: windows, cmd, pwd

How do I find the local path on Windows in a command prompt?

Comment: Very useful information, although I believe this now belongs in superuser.com

Answer (score 610, accepted):

This prints it in the console:

```
echo %cd%
```

or paste this command in CMD, then you'll have `pwd`:

```
(echo @echo off
echo echo ^%cd^%) > C:\WINDOWS\pwd.bat
```

Comment: i got access denied and searched for solution , it took time so switched to another answer `cd` only

Comment: This does not print the full directory name if you have accessed the directory via the ~ notation, e.g. "C:\PROGRA~3"

Comment: Why do you need to `echo`? Just `cd` by itself seems to work fine.

Comment: `cd /?` says `Type CD without parameters to display the current drive and directory.`

Comment: @shareef well when you wanna write into C:\windows you might need admin. but you could just write it somewhere you have permissions and add it to your path. the point of this second block is to basically have a pwd alias for convenience

Comment: if using as an argument to say `docker`, you can use ${PWD} if in windows powershell.  `%cd` is fine if using Cmd prompt.

Comment: `echo %cd%` doesn't work when chaining commands, e.g. `cd C:\ && echo %cd%` -> wrong output.

Comment: This doesn't work with `doskey` though. If you do `doskey pwd=echo %cd%` you'll permanently have it set to the working directory _when the `doskey` was run_. The correct approach is `doskey pwd=cd`.

Comment: It doesn't work in PowerShell, so not very robust for all window users

Comment: `cmd /C echo %cd%`
will work in both CMD and PowerShell

Answer (score 169):

It is `cd` for "current directory".

Comment: If you need it in a variable or so, using the %CD% pseudo-variable is probably easier.

Comment: Cute, but `cd` is for "change directory"

Comment: Related side note: While on Windows `cd` alone will print the current working directory, on Linux it will change to your user's home directory without printing anything. So beware if you're looking for something cross platform.

Comment: @DanielStevens the help line from `cd` says *Displays the name of or changes the current directory.*

Comment: @phuclv correct, the *Windows* documentation for [cd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cd) does say that. The *Linux* documentation for [cd](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/cdh.html) says that when no path is given, it will change to your home directory. My local man pages use the wording: *"Change the current directory to dir. if dir is not supplied, the value of the HOME shell variable is the default."*

Answer (score 30):

Open notepad as administrator and write:

```
@echo %cd%
```

Save it in c:\windows\system32\
with the name "pwd.cmd" (be careful not to save pwd.cmd.txt)

Then you have the pwd command.

Answer (score 28):

```
cd ,
```

it will give the current directory

```
D:\Folder\subFolder>cd ,
D:\Folder\subFolder
```

Comment: just `cd` is enough. The comma is useless

Comment: in cmd [`,`, `;`, `=` are also delimiters just like space and tab](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html), therefore `cd ,` is no different from `cd =;=` or `cd <space>`

Comment: Doesn't work anymore on Windows 10

Comment: @EricBurel it works in cmd. It has nothing to do with Windows 10 because it's a shell feature, and if you use a different shell like powershell then obviously it won't work. Each shell has different syntax and powershell is the default in many new installations

Answer (score 17):

`cd` without any parameters is equivalent to `pwd` on Unix/Linux.

From the console output of typing `cd /?`:

```
Displays the name of or changes the current directory.

[...]

Type CD without parameters to display the current drive and directory.
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just type

```
cd
```

it will return you the current path.

Comment: this is exactly like Daniel A. White's answer above. Why on earth duplicated answers on this got so many upvotes

Comment: bc it's shorter and people don't like reading? I do, so here it goes my downvote :'(

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell `pwd` is an alias to [`Get-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location?view=powershell-6) so you can simply run `pwd` in it like in bash

It can also be called from cmd like this `powershell -Command pwd` although `cd` or `echo %cd%` in cmd would work just fine

Comment: That's the right answer that works for both cmd and PowerShell. How to extract the path though?

Comment: Note that powershell is incapable of giving you the correctly normalized path (with properly-cased file/folder names that match what is on disk).  If you "Set-Location" to c:\myfolder, but the folder on disk is c:\MyFolder, powershell will happily report "c:\myfolder".  One way to get the proper casing is to use cmd from pwsh like this:
`Set-Location (cmd /c echo %cd%)`
That will normalize your path.

Comment: @EricBurel what do you mean by "extract the path"? `Get-Location`/`pwd` on powershell and `echo %cd%` on cmd already extract the current path

Comment: @theta-fish you can [do this](https://serverfault.com/q/431416/343888) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63527968/995714) to avoid spawning a new shell just for normalization

Answer (score 2):

It will show you the current path in the console, use the below command

```
echo %cd%
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly like the current accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

hmm - pwd works for me on Vista...

Final **EDIT**: it works for me on Vista because WinAvr installed pwd.exe and added \Program Files\WinAvr\Utils\bin to my path.

Comment: Nor vista. Are you using powershell?

Comment: I'm not using powershell.  I seem to recall something about command extensions but can't find a checkbox anywhere for that.  I've also got <tab> completion in my Command Prompt.  I could swear there used to be an applet in Control Panel to enable command extensions but I can't find it now.

Comment: Command extensions are enabled by default on Windows NT and later. Tab completion is separate from that and was available from Windows 2000 onwards and enabled by default since XP. pwd only works here because I have a pwd.cmd with "echo %cd%" in my path. You can use gcm pwd in Powershell to check where it comes from on your machine (sort of like which(1), only better).

Comment: gcm pwd reports that pwd is an Alias with a definition of Get-Location.

Comment: Late to the party but usually you can figure out the location where pwd is coming from by the command 'where' on command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Scripter>echo %cd%
C:\Documents and Settings\Scripter

C:\Documents and Settings\Scripter>
```

for Unix use `pwd` command

[Current working directory](http://scripterworld.blogspot.com/2009/08/unix-pwd-command-tells-you-where-you.html)

Comment: don't you see `for Unix use pwd command` useless? Because it's what the OP asked

Comment: Doesn't work in Powershell

Comment: @EricBurel that's so obvious. PowerShell uses different syntax and use `$` for variables like most other shells instead of `%%` like in cmd

Answer (score -2):

Use the below command

```bat
dir | find "Directory"
```

Comment: this won't work if there's a file or folder named "Directory" in the current directory, or if Windows language is not English, because output of `dir` is localized

Answer (score -5):

You can simply put "." the dot sign. I've had a cmd application that was requiring the path and I was already in the needed directory and I used the dot symbol.

Hope it helps.