# Are there any known issues calling pwd using %x in Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, rake, puppet, pwd

Recently at work, we encountered a bug in [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-open-source/).  I decided to try to fix the bug in my free time.  The first step in this process is getting it working using a git clone.  I went through the instructions, then I tried to use rake and I started getting this error:

```
PS C:\Puppet-Code\Puppet> rake
rake/gempackagetask is deprecated.  Use rubygems/package_task instead
The system cannot find the path specified.
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - pwd

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I ran it with --trace and got this:

```
PS C:\Puppet-Code\Puppet> rake --trace
rake/gempackagetask is deprecated.  Use rubygems/package_task instead
The system cannot find the path specified.
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - pwd
ext/packaging/tasks/00_utils.rake:198:in ``'
ext/packaging/tasks/00_utils.rake:198:in `get_pwd_version'
ext/packaging/tasks/00_utils.rake:171:in `get_dash_version'
ext/packaging/tasks/10_setupvars.rake:65:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Puppet-Code/Puppet/Rakefile:25:in `load'
C:/Puppet-Code/Puppet/Rakefile:25:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Puppet-Code/Puppet/Rakefile:25:in `each'
C:/Puppet-Code/Puppet/Rakefile:25:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
```

After looking at the file I found that this was the line in question:

```
%x{pwd}.strip.split('.')[-1]
```

I am using Powershell to run the rake file and when I run pwd directly in Powershell it works.  However, if I run it from within the irb using %x{pwd} I just get an error message that there is no such file or directory 'pwd'.  My understanding is that %x just passes that command to the shell (which I think is Powershell because that's where I'm running it from).

Can anyone explain why %x{pwd} is not working and what, if anything, I can do to fix it?

EDIT: I am using Powershell on Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did the rake task come from?

Comment: `%x{pwd}` works fine using irb on osx. are you using windows? if so, perhaps report the bug to the gem's maintainer?

Comment: @mbratch: rather than a bug, I was actually wondering if windows had a `pwd` shell command: "No such file or directory - pwd" would indicate that it's not recognizing it.

Comment: @Denis oh right. Indeed, it does not. Duh. The equivalent in Windows is just `cd` (unfortunately).

Comment: @mbratch Microsoft's Powershell does have pwd aliased to a command.

Comment: Ok thanks! Interesting. I just ran `irb` in a power shell and it just doesn't want to recognize `pwd` no matter what syntax I use for doing a system command (I tried several). It will do `cd` fine, however. There's something "special" about the way they implemented `pwd` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby by default backticks, `%x`, `system`, or `exec` will not run under PowerShell.

On Windows all system commands will be running under `cmd.exe`, even if you start the process, subshell, irb etc. in another shell. It doesn't matter - Ruby will always spawn `cmd.exe` to run any system command.

From the documentation of [`Kernel.exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec):

> The standard shell always means "/bin/sh" on Unix-like systems, same as ENV["RUBYSHELL"] (or ENV["COMSPEC"] on Windows NT series), and similar.

You can try and change `RUBYSHELL` or `COMSPEC` to reference PowerShell, however you might have a hard time getting it to work.

Instead I would try other solutions, like finding an equivalent `pwd` command that runs under `cmd.exe` and use that.

Or why not just use [`Dir.pwd`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-pwd).

Answer (score 2):

### Use OS-Agnostic Methods

Instead of relying on the shell to provide you with the current working directory, use [Dir#pwd](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-pwd) instead. For example:

```
directory = Dir.pwd
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use a Windows shell for this, you might look at [this older question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921741/windows-equivalent-to-unix-pwd) However, an OS-agnostic approach is usually sounder.

### Example

Given a current working directory of *C:\tmp\foo.bar* the Dir module should result in the following:

```
Dir.pwd.strip.split('.')[-1]
# => "bar"
```

Assuming that "bar" is indeed the string you're looking for, all should be well. If you're doing something more complicated, you may need to update your question.

Comment: +1. There is also the [Pathname](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/pathname/frames) class included with Ruby. It's like a blend of Dir and FileUtils.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting and expanding on the comments as the likely answer. If you're on windows, `pwd` is not available as a comment. You'd need to use `cd` or `echo %cd%`:

[Windows equivalent to UNIX pwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921741/windows-equivalent-to-unix-pwd)

Don't miss this answer in the above-mentioned thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4634089/417194

> Open notepad as administrator and write:
>
> ```
> @echo %cd%
> ```
>
> Save it in c:\windows\system32\ with the name "pwd.cmd" (be careful not to save pwd.cmd.txt)
>
> Then you have the pwd command.

There also is the built-in ruby function:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-pwd

Comment: @mnuzzo: perhaps it's not in the path when ruby opens a shell, or something?