# Get original file name case with PowerShell Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

When I use `Get-ChildItem` to get the information for a specific file, the case of the name in the file information is whatever I passed to `Get-ChildItem`. Is there any way to get the original name of the file, including case?

For example, say I have a file named "MyFile.txt". If I get the file information like this:

```
$SearchPath = 'somefolder\myfile.txt'
Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchPath
```

Then it returns something like this:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         8/21/2020   1:53 PM           1213 myfile.txt
```

Is there any way to get the file name with the original casing (e.g., "MyFile.txt")?

Comment: It's in the `.Name` property of the returned `FileInfo` or `DirectoryInfo` object.

Comment: @Theo the `Name` property returns the file name in lower case like shown, not in the original case.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just the File name (not the full path) you want returned in True-Case, below alternatives might prove much faster:

**Using 'dir'**

```
$SearchPath = 'D:\Test\somefolder\myfile.txt'
[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName((cmd /c dir $SearchPath /b /s /a-d))
```

**Using RoboCopy** (for this you need to split the file and directory)

```
$SearchPath = 'D:\Test\somefolder\myfile.txt'
$dir  = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($SearchPath)
$file = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($SearchPath)
[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName((robocopy $dir NULL $file /L /NDL /XX /NC /NS /NJH /NJS).Trim())
```

**Using `GetFileSystemEntries()`** (for this you need to split the file and directory)

```
$SearchPath = 'D:\Test\somefolder\myfile.txt'
$dir  = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($SearchPath)
$file = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($SearchPath)
[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName([System.IO.Directory]::GetFileSystemEntries($dir, $file)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution by taking advantage of the fact that `Get-ChildItem` returns the file names with their original case intact when invoked with a wildcard.

```
$SearchPath = 'somefolder\myfile.txt'
Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchPath |
ForEach-Object {
    $Pattern = $_.Directory.FullName + '\*.*'
    $FileName = $_.Name
    $OriginalName = (Get-ChildItem $Pattern | where { $_.Name -eq $FileName } | Select-Object -First 1).Name
    echo $OriginalName
}
```

I don't particularly like this since it involves enumerating all files in the folder. If there is a better way to do this, I'd love to hear it.

**Edit**

I was able to improve on my original solution by adding a wildcard to the target file name instead of enumerating all files, like so:

```bsh
$SearchPath = 'somefolder\myfile.txt'
Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchPath |
ForEach-Object {
    $Pattern = Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.FullName -ChildPath ($_.Name + '*')
    $FileName = $_.Name
    $OriginalName = (Get-ChildItem $Pattern | where { $_.Name -eq $FileName } | Select-Object -First 1).Name
    echo $OriginalName
}
```

I also found that certain .NET functions will return the file name in the original case while others don't. This combination of .NET functions works:

```
$SearchPath = 'somefolder\myfile.txt'
Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchPath |
ForEach-Object {
    $dir = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.DirectoryInfo -ArgumentList $_.Directory.FullName
    $OriginalName = ($dir.EnumerateFiles($_.Name) | Select-Object -First 1).Name
    echo $OriginalName
}
```