# 'pwd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: pwd

I am getting 'pwd' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file when I am trying to check my present working directory from cmd.
What should I do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows equivalent to UNIX pwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921741/windows-equivalent-to-unix-pwd)

Answer (score 0):

`pwd` is a Unix/Linux command. The Windows `cmd` equivalent is `cd` with no arguments.

Comment: This works on my windows development machine. It works in cmd.exe. I'd be interested to know why it works. I did install Git Bash